# analysis of alpha lattice design

Tags: experiment-design

Are there R some packages for analysis of alpha-lattice (0,1) designed experiment? My experiment includes two factors with two levels. The tests are performed in two replications with twenty blocks. Every block consists of 10 plots.

Answer (score 2):

The `PBIB.test()` function in package `agricolae` can be used for analysis of a field experiment in alpha lattice design.

Please refer the tutorial http://tarwi.lamolina.edu.pe/~fmendiburu/index-filer/download/ENagricolae.pdf , page no. `51` for a detailed worked out example for designing and analyzing an alpha lattice design.